# Losing precision when adding large natural number(with exponential notations) and small natural numbers in python 3

Tags: python, precision, exponentiation

```
    n = int(input())
    sum1 = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
    sum2 = int(sum1)
    sum2 = sum2 + 100
    sum1 = sum1 + 100
    if sum2 == sum:
        print("same")
    elif sum2 > sum1:
        print("less")
    elif sum2 < sum1:
        print("more")
    print("sum1=",sum1)
    print("sum2=",sum2)
```

INPUT:n=10000000000(or anything greater than 10^9)
OUTPUT:less
sum1= 5.0000000005e+19
sum2= 50000000005000003684

Both sum1 and sum2 should be equal but somehow i lose precision when exponentials come into play and if i tried to print the difference between sum1 and sum2 , i get zero(0.0) as output.For smaller values of n , i get accurate answers.

> So, How do i avoid losing precision and get exact results when i add really large integers and smaller integres?
> Note: This code is just a part of a larger program, so please keep your answers general.Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is an inherent limitation of floating point numbers. You can never get exact results using floating point numbers.

Comment: Keep everything as integers and you will be fine -- they are arbitrary precision in Python. If `n` is an integer then `n * (n+1)` must be divisible by 2, so instead of `n * (n+1) / 2`, use integer division i.e. `n * (n+1) // 2` and you will get an integer with the value that the floating-point value *would* have if it had sufficient precision. The problem you are getting is *not* adding larger and smaller integers as the question claims, but it is with adding *floats* after you have created them using the `/` division operator.

Comment: For more information on the problems with `float` types see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5987)

Answer (score 2):

As alani points out, there is an implicit conversion to `float` in `sum1 = (n * (n + 1)) / 2`.  E.g.  `isinstance(1/1, float) == True`.  Use integer division `//`.  `n*(n+1)` is always even so you will never have an `N.5` result where you lose accuracy.  Also, the `repr` of `float`s is always either with a decimal point (`1.0`) or an exponent (`1e+20`) or both, so if you ever see that, you know you have floats.

Comment: Not just `repr` but `str` too, which is what `print` will use.